# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 rmnet0 interface non existent

Tags: wi-fi, adb, networking, shell

I was wondering, why in my Samsung Galaxy 2 tablet I can't see any rmnet0 interface after executing:

```
adb shell cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats
```

Or:

```
adb shell netcfg
```

I know this a wifi only device, so, is this maybe the reason behind this?

The device is already connected to internet via my wifi router, I can navigate, see videos, etc etc

But for some reason I only got the wlan0 internal Ip from it, no rmnet0.

Is that a 3G network interface only?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WiFi, you only have the IP address of your local network, that's completely normal. `rmnet` interfaces are for mobile data – which would explain why you don't see them on a WiFi only device.

> `rmnet` interfaces are usually associated with [cellular connections and usb tethering](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-flo-3.4-kitkat-mr1/Documentation/usb/gadget_rmnet.txt)

<sup>from: [Android NetworkInterface. What are the meanings of names of NetworkInterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33747787/2533433)</sup>